# Bootstrap date picker in arabic showing extended white background

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I am getting an extended white background in the date picker in arabic page.

http://s13.postimg.org/lg52caopz/date_picker_issue_arabic.png

The code used

```
    $('.input-group.date').datepicker({
        format: "mm/dd/yy",
        weekStart: 0,
        calendarWeeks: true,
        autoclose: true,
        todayHighlight: true,
        rtl: true,
        orientation: "auto"
    });
```

JS versions used

jQuery v1.11.2 
Bootstrap v3.3.4
Datepicker for Bootstrap v1.4.0

It would really helpful if someone could look into this.

Comment: Set a width to the datepicker.

Comment: Have you checked for other classes messing up with your datepicker?

Comment: Thank you guys for the help. I changed the date picker in arabic as I had to deliver sooner